# Laravel Mutators and Accessors

Tags: laravel, mutators

I have created mutator date function in model to convert the created_at date into human readable time using **diffForHumans()**.
I have done the following

```
public function setDateAttribute($value){
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
}
```

It works fine but it affects in all. it is possible to apply this mutator only on the specified function of the controller rather than all function

Comment: what do you mean by 'affects in all' ? mutators only works when you call them.

Comment: I want to call them on the specific function of the controller.currently it parses and set date in another function of the controller. that I don't want I just want my mutator function in my index method did not edit or show methods

Comment: edit your question and put a sample code of where you did use this mutator

Comment: `public function getLeadProductDateAttribute($value){
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
}`  this is my mutator function. it is call automatically. but i want to call that function on specific controller function

Comment: again, this is function declaration, show us where did you use this.

Comment: I want to use it in my controller in index method

Comment: The problem here Mr. Khandar, is I think you misunderstood the Accesors and Mutators, thats why I asked you a usage of this mutator. But if you don't co-operate with me I can't help you. Your Question is not clear, that's why no one has answered it yet.

Comment: I will explain you in details.`public function getLeadProductDateAttribute($value){ return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans(); }` this is my mutator function that will be in model.i want to call this function in specific condition now it is call automatically that i dont want.

Comment: this function doesn't call automatically, this function only calls when you access this attribute. that's why it's call `Accessors`

Answer (score 0):

A small logic in the mutator would do the job:-

```
    public function setDateAttribute($value){
       if ( request()->path() === "/yourURL/To/IndexMethod"){ 
         return $this->attributes['date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
       } else {
         return $this->attributes['date'] = $value;
       }
    }
```

the idea is to check by the url.

[getting request path helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#request-path-and-method)

**EDIT**

Comparison using route name is better, as exact path can contain id/slugs.

```
public function setDateAttribute($value){
       if ( \Route::currentRouteName() === "/yourRouteName/To/IndexMethod"){ 
         return $this->attributes['date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
       } else {
         return $this->attributes['date'] = $value;
       }
    }
```

[getting route name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

Comment: it print the path with id not method

Comment: **comparing using route names** will get rid of id/slugs